# Wordpress variables and memory

Tags: variables, memory

When checking get_defined_vars() on an empty template file my theme loads over 70000 lines of output. Before even including elements on a page all of this is loaded.

1. Is this correct?
2. Is there any way to reduce it or remove unnecessary variables?
3. Do all wp_rewrite rules have to be available for every page load?

Comment: If your crazy you can `define('SHORTINIT', true);` and then load in each bit of WordPress that you want manually.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, a lot of information gets loaded. I just put `print_r` in my `header.php` on 3.5.1 and got nowhere near 70000 lines though. I got about 2110 and that includes some post body content. Also, `print_r` or `var_dump` are formatted representations, remember. Things are not actually stored in memory that way.
2. I doubt you could remove much this stuff without breaking something or causing other negative effects. You  are talking about Core hacks to do it. Some autoloaded items could probably be removed but if you did that you'd get extra database queries when those items are needed. I doubt it would be worth it.
3. WordPress calculates rewrites on every page load. How is it to find the right page unless all of the rewrite rules are present? Of everything, these would be the most difficult to get rid of, unless you want to use the default permalinks.

Are you actually experiencing a problem? Or is this preemptive?

**counts using toscho's code, for the sake of comparison**

```
160 $GLOBALS
79  variables
29  constants
```

Comment: no this is a problem I am experiencing. There seems to a be a memory leak..

Comment: Well, it seems to be something specific to your site/server as I don't get anywhere near 70000 lines of data on a fairly pristine 3.5.1 install. Switch off your plugins and switch to a default theme and see if you still have the issues.

Comment: my vanilla install: 163 $GLOBALS 10014 variables - how could this be server related if not theme / plugin related?

Comment: It is curious that you and toscho have so many more defined variables than I do. I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: It is possible you have an opcode cache on and it is effecting it?

Comment: Actually I don't think that makes any difference, I wonder why this is.

Comment: I don't have an opcode cache. It is a dev server-- no need. It is very puzzling I copied toscho's code exactly, at least that variables line.

Answer (score 4):

Your installation might be … less than optimal.

Using my [Mini Theme](https://github.com/toscho/Toscho-s-Mini-Theme), no plugins and the following code on the front page right after the opening `body` tag …

```
print count( $GLOBALS ) . ' $GLOBALS<br>';
print @count( get_defined_vars(), 1 ) . ' variables<br>';
print count( get_defined_constants( TRUE )['user'] ) . ' constants';
```

… I get:

```
 158 $GLOBALS
9759 variables
  85 constants
```

Still too much for my taste. Keep in mind many plugin and theme developers forget to keep the global namespace clean. Depending on the quality of the addons you have installed your results might be much higher.

And yes, you need those rewrite rules. Some slugs are translated, and translation can change on each request. So they have to be always available.

Comment: I get a parse error on that `get_defined_constants` line. It is triggered at the first `[` and `$u = get_defined_constants( TRUE ); print count($u['user']);` give me an undefined index error. Possibly a PHP version issue?

Comment: Yes, very outdated PHP versions don’t understand that syntax. :P

Comment: Yes... 5.3.3... ancient :) I don't know why I get the undefined index error though.

Comment: on my install now with only really neccesary plugins: 192 $GLOBALS
13776 variables - still loads of variables

Comment: @Innate There are no necessary plugins. :)